# jCarousel - Continue Scrolling When At First or Last Item On Button Press

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I am encountering an issue with jCarousel whereby if a the carousel has started at the beginning and the left button is pressed the carousel doesn't scroll.

What is supposed to happen is that if the carousels first item is displayed and the left button is pressed, the carousel should circle to the end item. At the moment, this does not happen. The carousel just stops working.

This only happens when the carousel is first loaded.

Example of my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/wquPu/2/.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are doing wrong, but if you look at the jCarousel demo pages you will find a demo of exactly what you are trying to do and it's very simple code.

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last',
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
```

Comment: But when the scroll buttons are pressed, scrolling is disasbled. With my code, I am continuing scrolling in whatever direction the user selects. The only issue I am having is when I want to scroll to the beginning. It should either scroll to the last element in a circular fashion or automatically start scrolling forward.

Comment: so you have to keep movving the last (or first if you are scrolling left) li to the beginning. I have not finished writing a very long blog post on how I solved this yet. But you can see my example site and examine the code. http://m.movie.extremewebworks.com