# how to use Continue Scrolling When At First or Last Item On Button Press

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to use up,down Key to Continue Scrolling i.e if I Press up then Scroll in upward direction or vise versa not one click

**Example:**

```
> http://jsfiddle.net/hazim/jLfdf2zh/
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hazim/jLfdf2zh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jLfdf2zh/2/

```
//<![CDATA[
$(function () {
    $('#button_up').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#button_down').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#button_down').click(
    function (e) {
        var posY = $('html').scrollTop();
        posY += 300;
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: posY
        }, 800);
    });
    $('#button_up').click(
    function (e) {
        var posY = $('html').scrollTop();
        posY -= 300;
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: posY
        }, 800);
    });
});
//]]>
```

***UPDATE***

http://jsfiddle.net/jLfdf2zh/3/

Comment: Fantastic . But Can I make continue scrolling  when the button is pressed not to scroll at every click

Comment: This is exactly what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8615582/3337380

Comment: i want like this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441975/jcarousel-continue-scrolling-when-at-first-or-last-item-on-button-press?rq=1

Comment: that is great . thank u bro i try it in google chrome not work but work fine in firefox